# Multiple select in and do a Delete after

Tags: sql

I would like to know how to convert a select query with multiple select in `( )` into a delete query. `Field1` is a *primary key* in all the tables.

Query:

```
select field1 from table1 where field1 in
(select field1 from table2 where field19<>777) and field1 in
(select field1 from table2 where field19=777) and field1 in
(select field1 from table3 where field8=0 or field8 is null)
```

Comment: `field19<>777` and `field19=777` from `table2` at th same time returns no row

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it’s to late ;) it will return all the field1 so I can have the total numbers of field1 but we don’t want to delete field1, so it’s not possible. This will need to be done with a Join.
Thanks we can close this post.

Comment: To "close" this question you have to accept your answer